# Adding srcset to an automatically generated PHP gallery

Tags: php, html

I have a gallery script written in PHP, which generates a gallery based on images stored in a given folder. This is working fine for a straight ahead gallery, but I would like to add an srcset value, which generates the gallery from images in a folder marked "big" for high definition screens.

I have tried to replicate the part of the code which generates the small images by including a variable called $imagesBig, but it's only echoing the final image in the folder for each picture generated.

The file names in each folder are identical, only the folder variable changes.

```
<?php 
 $rsContent = "rsContent";
 $imgContainer = "imgContainer";

 $directoryBig = "img/acts/".$category."/".$thisPage."/gallery/big/";
 $imagesBig = glob($directoryBig . "*.jpg");
 foreach($imagesBig as $imageBig);

 $directorySmall = "img/acts/".$category."/".$thisPage."/gallery/small/";
 $imagesSmall = glob($directorySmall . "*.jpg");
 foreach($imagesSmall as $imageSmall) {

 echo "<div class=" .$rsContent. "><div class=" .$imgContainer. "><img src=" .$imageSmall. " srcset='$imageSmall 1x, $imageBig 2x' alt=" .$thisPage. " /></div></div>";

}

?>
```

I'm hoping the final output will look like this:

```
<div class="rsContent">
 <div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="img/acts/theater/kikkerkusje/gallery/small/1.jpg" srcset="img/acts/theater/kikkerkusje/gallery/small/1.jpg 1x, img/acts/theater/kikkerkusje/gallery/big/1.jpg 2x" alt="kikkerkusje">
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two completly separate loops, the 'big' loop doesn't actually do anything (the `;` on the end of the `foreach()`) just iterates over the loop with no output.

You need to combine the two sets of results, this assumes that the list of images will appear in the same order in each directory (something a bit fragile - you may be better sorting the lists if this may be a problem).

First get a list of the big images and then when outputting the small images in a loop, pick out the matching big image (using `$imagesBig[$index]`)...

```
$directoryBig = "img/acts/".$category."/".$thisPage."/gallery/big/";
$imagesBig = glob($directoryBig . "*.jpg");

$directorySmall = "img/acts/".$category."/".$thisPage."/gallery/small/";
$imagesSmall = glob($directorySmall . "*.jpg");
foreach($imagesSmall as $index=>$imageSmall) {

     $imageBig = $imagesBig[$index];
     echo "<div class=" .$rsContent. "><div class=" 
          .$imgContainer. "><img src=" .$imageSmall
          . " srcset='$imageSmall 1x, $imageBig 2x' alt=" 
          .$thisPage. " /></div></div>";

}
```